# Tkinter- Prevent frames from flattening the last children?

Tags: tkinter

I have a frame that contains several children one above the other (with pack) but the last one does not fit completely inside the frame and is automatically flattened.

Is there a way to prevent this and let the child go out of the frame without being resized?

```
actions_frame = tk.Frame(right_frame)
actions_frame.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='nsew')

for i in range(1,30):
   action_button = tk.Button(actions_frame, text='Action ' + str(i))
   action_button.pack(fill=tk.X)
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Post the code where the other can help you.

Comment: You're forcing it into a space that isn't big enough. What do you want to happen? Do you want the last frame to not be visible, or for the outer frame to grow, or for all of the inner frames to shrink the same so that they all fit?

Comment: @BryanOakley I would like the last one to come out of the screen without being resized.

Comment: We cannot reproduce the issue without a [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 This issue is not difficult to reproduce, you can use this code

`import tkinter as tk
frame = tk.Frame(width=200, height=500)
frame.pack(fill = tk.Y, expand=True)
button1 = tk.Button(frame, text='Button 1')
button1.pack(fill=tk.X)
button2 = tk.Button(frame, text='Button 2')
button2.pack(fill=tk.X)`

Answer (score 0):

- If you do `for i in range(1,30):` You get **29** buttons.
- If you do `for i in range(1,31):` You get **30** buttons.

Screenshot **29** buttons and **30** buttons:

[image]     [image]